# XML SQL Searching without ID field name

Tags: sql, xml

I'm trying to do a simple SQL XML search but because of how the data is randomly stored in the XML I'm having a hard time figuring out how to search the XML to display the search parameters.

I have a field called ParameterStr that holds XML data like shown below.
I need to display the  node value.

Below is my code, but all I get when I try search for the  is zero's. The  varies per order entry so I cannot key of off that node.

Any help would be great.
CODE:

```
GO
DECLARE @SearchForT1 NVARCHAR(100)
set @SearchForT1 = 'T_Minus1';

select ParameterStr.exist ('/Parameters/Parameter[VariableName=sql:variable("@SearchForT1")]/valueasstring[0]') from tbl_TextXMLData
```

XML IN Field: ParameterStr

```
<Parameters>
   <Parameter>
     <VariableID>(10203,14505)</VariableID>
     <VariableName>RushFee</VariableName>
     <ValueAsString>0</ValueAsString>
   </Parameter>
   <Parameter>
     <ID>(132979,14030)</ID>
     <VariableID>(10314,14505)</VariableID>
     <VariableName>T_Minus3</VariableName>
     <ValueAsString>01/13/2017 4:00PM</ValueAsString>
     <ValueAsDateTime>01/13/2017 4:00PM</ValueAsDateTime>
   </Parameter>
   <Parameter>
     <ID>(132978,14030)</ID>
     <VariableID>(10313,14505)</VariableID>
     <VariableName>T_Minus2</VariableName>
     <ValueAsString>01/16/2017 4:00PM</ValueAsString>
   </Parameter>
   <Parameter>
     <ID>(132977,14030)</ID>
     <VariableID>(10312,14505)</VariableID>
     <VariableName>T_Minus1</VariableName>
     <ValueAsString>01/17/2017 4:00PM</ValueAsString>
   </Parameter>
 </Parameters>
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a **SQL database** - SQL is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by many database systems, but it's not a database product. Many things like XML support are **highly** vendor-specific - so we really need to know **what database system** (and which version) you're using.... (please update tags accordingly)

Answer (score 0):

Though I am not sure whether the xpath statement meets your requirement, but at least it returns `true` if you change the last step into `/ValueAsString`:

```
DECLARE @x xml  
SET @x = '<Parameters>
   <Parameter>
     <VariableID>(10203,14505)</VariableID>
     <VariableName>RushFee</VariableName>
     <ValueAsString>0</ValueAsString>
   </Parameter>
   <Parameter>
     <ID>(132979,14030)</ID>
     <VariableID>(10314,14505)</VariableID>
     <VariableName>T_Minus3</VariableName>
     <ValueAsString>01/13/2017 4:00PM</ValueAsString>
     <ValueAsDateTime>01/13/2017 4:00PM</ValueAsDateTime>
   </Parameter>
   <Parameter>
     <ID>(132978,14030)</ID>
     <VariableID>(10313,14505)</VariableID>
     <VariableName>T_Minus2</VariableName>
     <ValueAsString>01/16/2017 4:00PM</ValueAsString>
   </Parameter>
   <Parameter>
     <ID>(132977,14030)</ID>
     <VariableID>(10312,14505)</VariableID>
     <VariableName>T_Minus1</VariableName>
     <ValueAsString>01/17/2017 4:00PM</ValueAsString>
   </Parameter>
 </Parameters>';

DECLARE @SearchForT1 NVARCHAR(100)
set @SearchForT1 = 'T_Minus1';

SELECT @x.exist('/Parameters/Parameter[VariableName=sql:variable("@SearchForT1")]/ValueAsString');
```

Output:

```
(No column name)
----------------
True
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

```
ParameterStr.query('/Parameters/Parameter[VariableName=sql:variable("@SearchForT1")]/ValueAsString/text()[1]')
```